# Accessing Android app's internal files dir

Tags: android, android-storage

I'm creating an app that should, as an intermediate step, output some data to a file in the app's [internal file dir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()).  How can I test that the file's contents are created properly, given that `adb` won't let me copy this file onto the developer's machine?

```
adb pull /data/user/0/com.example.myapp/files/output.png

adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/files/output.png': Permission denied
```

I can run the adb shell under the app's linux user, but then I can only perform the checks that are available via the command-line, so I cannot e.g. see the picture with my own eyes.

I can write the same file to the external storage that is accessible, but aside from it requires additional code to get the write-external-storage permission, it doesn't test the same thing.

I can also root the phone, but I feel that to access my file on my app-under-development on my phone, it's pretty ridiculous to require such a drastic step as rooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it on an emulator using the Device File Explorer in Android Studio. But for a physical device you'll need to root it.

Comment: An unrooted physical device works as well (likely only after USB Debugging is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following permission your project manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

or your emulator or device check the permission . The permission are setting apps.